# Is there an obvious difference between the graph of a quadratic equation and the graph of an exponential equation?

Tags: exponential-function, graphing-functions, quadratics

I am having trouble identifying an exponential graph from a quadratic graph and my exams are soon. Is there an obvious difference between the two?

Comment: Limit at $\pm \infty$ ? And injectivity ?

Comment: I probably sound very stupid but could you explain what that means?

Comment: For $y=a^x$, every time you increase $x$ by $1$, $y$ increases by a factor of $a$. This means that exponential functions generally increase (if $a > 1$) or decrease (if $0 < a < 1$) *much* faster than quadratics. The slope of a quadratic function changes more gradually. Also, a quadratic curve is symmetric, while an exponential shoots up on one side and is flat on the other.